# Export list as .txt (Python)

Tags: python, list, csv, export, tuples

My Python module has a list that contains all the data I want to save as a .txt file somewhere. The list contains several tuples like so:

```
list = [ ('one', 'two', 'three'), ('four', 'five', 'six')]
```

How do I print the list so each tuple item is separated by a tab and each tuple is separated by a newline?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print '\n'.join('\t'.join(x) for x in L)
```

Comment: Says 'sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found'

Answer (score 9):

You can solve it, as other answers suggest by just joining lines but better way would be to just use python csv module, so that later on you can easily change delimter or add header etc and read it back too, looks like you want tab delimited file

```
import sys
import csv

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t')
rows = [ ('one', 'two', 'three'), ('four', 'five', 'six')]
csv_writer.writerows(rows)
```

output:

```
one two three
four    five    six
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method but I'm too beginner to try it :)

Comment: but in way it is much simpler, because you just use std libs, but yes for a beginner you must also know how to do it hardway :)

Comment: Good solution.  Don't use 'list' for a variable name, though.

Comment: -1 Now explain to the beginner how to do it without StringIO, which introduces unwanted complexity and is slow, and with output to a file. 5 upvoters???

Comment: @John Machin, are we writing a beginners tutorial or correct solution, writing csv is not as trivial as it sounds and it is better to use a standard lib if available, and StringIO is used in many places in python where interface takes file type objects

Comment: @Anurag; I don't understand your question. csv is fine; I've got no grip with that at all. Mr gripe is with StringIO. The OP wanted to "save as .txt file" then wanted to "print the list" -- both of these can be done very simply (the latter by `import sys; csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t')`) with standard file objects without the baroque StringIO.

Comment: @John Machin, ok got it, yes StringIO wasn't needed here, removed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"\n".join(map("\t".join,l))
```

Test

```
>>> l = [ ('one', 'two', 'three'), ('four', 'five', 'six')]
>>> print "\n".join(map("\t".join,l))
one     two     three
four    five    six
>>>
```

Comment: `map` builds lists -- unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
open("data.txt", "w").write("\n".join(("\t".join(item)) for item in list))
```

Comment: says  'argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not generator'

Answer (score 1):

The most idiomatic way, IMHO, is to use a list comprehension and a join:

```
print '\n'.join('\t'.join(i) for i in l)
```

Comment: I see no list comprehension here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to join the list in advance:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as fp:
    fp.writelines('%s\n' % '\t'.join(items) for items in a_list)
```